# SimpleXML - Android - CDATA parsing

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing, cdata, simple-framework

I'm using SimpleXML for parsing XML files in Android.  I need to parse the following XML,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Box>
    <SerialNumber>XYSSDSD</SerialNumber>
    <Alias><![CDATA[SSS: 8]]></Alias>
    <BoxType>SD</BoxType>
</Box>
```

I wrote Bean class to map the above xml

```
@Element(name="SerialNumber")
private String serialNumber;
@Element(name="Alias", data=true)
private String aliasType;  
@Element(name="BoxType")
private String boxType;
```

I'm getting the following exception while parsing the XML

> 1-24 23:57:47.407: E/Exception in APItoBEAN(1796): Unable to satisfy
>   @org.simpleframework.xml.Element(data=true, name=Alias, required=true,
>   type=void) on field 'aliasType' private .Box.aliasType for class Box
>   at line 1

Could you anybody help me here?
Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2):

I tested this on PC (SimpleXML 2.6.6) with following Java Code:

**Box Class:**

```
@Root
public class Box
{
    @Element(name = "SerialNumber")
    private String serialNumber;
    @Element(name = "Alias", data = true)
    private String aliasType;
    @Element(name = "BoxType")
    private String boxType;

    // ...
}
```

**Reading the XML:**

```
final File f = new File("test.xml"); // your XML is in this file


Serializer ser = new Persister();
Box box = ser.read(Box.class, f);
```

Works without exception.

Did you clean your project and build it again? Your code seems to be OK.